# Create a function that runs every interval and stop that function from running with Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-handler, android-looper

I want to create a function that runs every 50ms (the equivalent of `setInterval` in JS). So far, this is what I have:

```
val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
mainHandler.post(object: Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        progressBar.progress += 1
        mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 50)
    }
})
```

It works, but how do I stop the `run()` function from running any further when the progress has reached `100`? Also, is there a way to cancel the `run` and reset `progress` to `0` when I click a button (like `clearInterval` in JS)? For reference, I want this:

```
buttonView.setOnClickListener {
    stopRunFromRunning()
    resetProgressTo0()
}

progress.onReach100 {
    stopRunFromRunning()
}
```

Comment: You can `return`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assign the runnable into a variable and you can remove from handler's callback

```
val progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
val btn = findViewById(R.id.btn)

val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
val runnable = Runnable {
    override public fun run() {
     progressBar.progress+=1
       if(progressBar.progress<100)
          handler.postDelayed(this, 50) 
    }
}

handler.post(runnable, milliseconds)

btn.setOnClickListener {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    progressBar.progress=0
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer any of his questions

Comment: Actually, it does.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it's not a complete answer. Believe me, I just won my new hat :)

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. However, if you have time, please do add some implementation on the other conditions I mentioned (on button click and on progress reaching 100, e.g. by adding `return` inside the `run()` after progress reaches 100 and removing itself from its `run()`). I will accept your answer after that.

Answer (score 0):

when working with progressbar, I do something like:

```
var stop = false
val runnable = Runnable {
       while (progressBar.progress < 100) {
            if(stop) break

            progressBar.progress += 1
            // Try to sleep the thread for 50 milliseconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
       }
}
Thread(runnable).start()

// stop
stopButtonClick -> {
    stop = true
    progressBar.progress = 0
}
```

now you can tell your counter to stop before `progressBar.progress = 100` and your counter also knows when to stop itself. Hope it helps